# I cannot get Emacs to stop asking me about adding a newline at the end of file

Tags: if-statement, emacs, trailing-newline

Emacs keeps on asking me

```
Buffer text.txt does not end in newline.  And one? (y or n)
```

I am confused about why I cannot stop Emacs from making this inquiry.  I've set both

```
require-final-newline
mode-require-final-newline
```

to `nil` in a hook to `tex-mode`.

I've verified that it's value is indeed `nil` when I'm working in my file.  But nevertheless, Emacs continues to make the inquiry.

I've looked at the code for `basic-save-buffer`.  The relevant part of the code is:

```
       (or (eq require-final-newline t)
           (eq require-final-newline 'visit-save)
           (and require-final-newline
            (y-or-n-p
             (format "Buffer %s does not end in newline.  Add one? "
                 (buffer-name)))))
```

It seems that Emacs should never get to the `y-or-n-p` since it appears as the second part of an `and` test where the first part evaluates to `nil`.

What's going on here?

My Emacs is GNU 27.2.

I've played a bit rewriting this code.  As an example,

```
       (or (eq require-final-newline t)
           (eq require-final-newline 'visit-save)
           (and nil
            (y-or-n-p
             (format "Buffer %s does not end in newline.  Add one? "
                 (buffer-name)))))
```

Behaves as I would expect.

I've also tried something like:

```
       (or (eq require-final-newline t)
           (eq require-final-newline 'visit-save)
           (and require-final-newline
                        (progn
                          (message (concat "[2] require-final-newline: " (format "%S" require-final-newline)))
                          (sit-for 1)
                          t)
            (y-or-n-p
             (format "Buffer %s does not end in newline.  Add one? "
                 (buffer-name)))))
```

And the message reports that `require-final-newline` is `nil` but the only way to get to the message is for it to be `t`.

What's going on?

UPDATE

I am able to go in and customize the variable.  And when I do that and set it to `Don't add newlines`, the annoying question goes away.  But, I'm not happy with this.  That seems to set this value globally regardless of the mode I'm in.  That's not what I want.  It's just for specific files and when in `tex-mode` that I want this to apply.

Further update:

@phils 's questions have been very useful, actually, for me to begin to debug what's going on  here.

I think I've located the problem.  I'm still interested how to solve it.

I'm using a `.dir-locals.el` to set a number of parameters for the local files I'm working on.  If I remove the `.dir-locals.el` file and set things via hooks (as I formerly believed I was doing), everything behaves properly.

However, if I use the `.dir-locals.el` file set parameters, then things stop working properly.  In the `.dir-locals.el` file I have the following line:

```
(nil . ((require-final-newline nil)))
```

This seems to be the problem.  What's happening is that instead of `require-final-newline` getting set to `nil` it is getting set to `(nil)`.

I can stick with the use of a *hook* to accomplish what I want.  But, now I'm curious.  Am I getting the syntax for `.dir-locals.el` wrong.  Here's my full `.dir-locals.el` file

```
(
 (nil . ((fill-column . 70)))
 (nil . ((mode .tex)))
 (nil . ((require-final-newline nil)))
)
```

Comment: Why `tex-mode` ??

Comment: @phils I don't understand the question.  It's the mode I use to write to many of my files.

Comment: You've associated `.txt` filenames like "text.txt" with `tex-mode` rather than the normal `text-mode`??  `tex-mode` is for TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: @phils I'm aware of that.  There are feature of `tex-mode` I find useful which don't exist in `text-mode`.  What does that have to do with my question?

Comment: I asked because you'd added a hook to `tex-mode` and were confused that it wasn't working for a `text.txt` file, and by default that would be expected.  It looked like *that* might have been your problem.

Comment: @phils Thank you for explaining your point.  I understand now.  Without going into the nuts-and-bolts of why I occasionally use `tex-mode` for `txt` files, I've set up a `.dir-locals.el` file to invoke `tex-mode` for this particular `.txt` file (and others that share this directory).

Comment: @phils I am truly grateful to you for you questions.  I didn't understand what you were after, but you did get me looking closer at things I had not considered being the culprit.  I've now figured out the error.  Everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I encountered is due to a syntax error in my `.dir-locals.el` file.

I have a line in that file which reads

```
(nil . ((require-final-newline nil)))
```

that is wrong.  It sets `require-final-newline` to `(nil)`, not `nil`.

If I correct the *syntax* to

```
(nil . ((require-final-newline . nil)))
```

everything works as desired and as expected.

Comment: You probably know, but see `C-h i g (elisp)Dotted Pair Notation` if you're not sure why that value ended up as `(nil)` before.

Comment: And these days (since Emacs 27.1) `M-x add-dir-local-variable` generates dotted notation for the (var . value) pairs, so you can use that to update the file without it ending up hard to read.  It'll get confused by your file having multiple `nil` keys, though, so make sure you fix that.

Comment: @phils Thank you for the heads up and the references.  I hadn't known (obviously) about the error of using multiple `nil`.  I don't remember when I started using `.dir-locals.el`.  But it was a very long time ago when I knew only a small fraction of what I do now.  I'll have to research `.dir-locals.el` syntax some more.  I'm sure I've got other quacky things going on.

Comment: Note that the correct structure is `((nil . ((fill-column . 70) (mode . tex) (require-final-newline . nil))))`.  As well as the multiple `nil` keys you had another typo in `(mode .tex)` instead of `(mode . tex)` -- the former considers the dot to be part of the mode symbol, rather than as a dotted pair separator, so that value was the list `(\.tex)`